# In Local Host Payment Gateway works fine but on server it gives following error

Tags: c#, asp.net

> System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.

Answer (score 0):

May be on sever you will be needing 64 bit dlls of your payment gateway system(if you are using any dlls)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a trust error; I expect you are running on full trust locally and medium trust on the server. You could be doing all sorts of things causing this problem, but one to consider straight away is this: Are you acessing your web/config at all? Take a look here: [Another Security Exception on GoDaddy after Login attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304616/another-security-exception-on-godaddy-after-login-attempt/2488591#2488591)